Django 5.0, Display flash message in form and retain input values
I have an email submission form with 3 input fields:
#forms.py

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "* Your name"})
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "* Your email address"})
    )
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "* Your message"})
    )

When a user submits the form, a flash message appears below the submit button confirming that the message has been sent.
#contact.html

<section id="form">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <h3>Send me an email</h3>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div 
                    class="text-center alert alert-{{ message.tags }}"
                    >
                        {{ message|safe }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </section>

#views.py

class ContactPageView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "contact.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact')  # Return back to the page containing the form
    success_message = "Your message has been sent. Thankyou."

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")

        # Displays in console
        full_message = f"""
            Email received from <{name}> at <{email}>,
            ________________________

            {message}
            """
        send_mail(
            subject="Email from client using website form",
            message=full_message,
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            recipient_list=[settings.NOTIFY_EMAIL],
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)

The form works fine except that I would like the input values retained after the form has been submitted and with the flash message still displayed.
I've tried including a get_success_url function below the form_valid function hoping that the values would be displayed back in the form, but I get the following attribute error:
'ContactPageView' object has no attribute 'name'.
#views.py

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'contact',
        kwargs={
            'name': self.name,
            'email': self.email,
            'message': self.message,
        },
    )

I'm new to Django, so could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.
